# How to compare two xml nodes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

My XML node have 6 attributes but the thing is from these attributes I need to check weather 2 attributes are equal or not. If equal then the the entry should be omitted otherwise must be written in XML file

I am trying code

```
private static bool checkDuplication(XmlElement Xtemp, XmlNodeList xmlNodeList)
{
    foreach (XmlNode node in xmlNodeList)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ComparableAttributes.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (node == Xtemp)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
     }
     return false;
}
```

Its not working!

Comment: The title seems misleading, offtopic but you need to stick to one style of indicating braces

Comment: You want to remove duplicate data from xml file? Isnt it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot modify `web.config` at runtime, since when it is changed, your Application restarts.

In addition, I'm not sure, but I think think comparing XmlNode and XmlElement with simple == will not work since it compares references only and not objects content